# How to update a legacy Android project using Android Studio without using Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I've an old project developed using Eclipse. Now, I want to use Android Studio to continue to development (for the sake of better IDE), but I don't want to use Gradle.

I was able to build/debug the project when I open the legacy project using Android Studio, but I find no way to update an existing jar in the `libs` folder.

What I found on the interweb is that I need to use Gradle, but I don't even have a Gradle file right now, so, it is possible to replace a newer version of jar in `libs` folder without using Gradle?

Comment: "Now, I want to use Android Studio to continue to development (for the sake of better IDE), but I don't want to use Gradle" -- then how are you planning on having Android Studio build the app? Are you going to use Maven or something? "I don't even have a Gradle file right now" -- that is highly unlikely, unless you manually set up some alternative build system (e.g., Maven). You might also explain specifically what your problems are with using Gradle, as perhaps it would be simpler for us to help you with those specific problems.

Comment: Actually I also don't understand, I just open the existing eclipse project and I was able to build by clicking the Build button from Android Studio, seems like they auto converted the project for me.

Comment: Right, and if it was a fairly normal project import, Android Studio would have set up two `build.gradle` files (one at the top level, one in an `app/` module), plus a `settings.gradle` file. Android Studio uses Gradle as its native build system, which is why you have to go through a chunk of work to not use Gradle, and that "chunk of work" would require setting up some other build system (e.g., Maven).

Comment: Strange that I don't have any gradle file under my current project `find . | grep gradle` return nothing